# TDictionary поиск в файле

Tags: delphi

Как, осуществить **поиск строк в файле**, по **ключевому слову**, используя **TDictionary**. Как мне кажется через TDictionary будет быстрее работать алгоритм.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Vhod, Vihod: TextFile;
  S: string;
  i: integer;
  Dictionary: TDictionary<string, integer>;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Dictionary := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create;
    AssignFile(Vhod, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    reset(Vhod);
    AssignFile(Vihod, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\svr_files.txt');
    rewrite(Vihod);
  end;

  // Предполагаю что тут нужно подключить тут
  Dictionary := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create;

  while not Eof(Vhod) do
  begin
    ReadLn(Vhod, S);

    // Предполагаю что и тут нужно подключить
    if (Dictionary.ContainsKey(S)) then

      if (Pos('Что ищем', S) > 0) then
        writeln(Vihod, S);
  end;

  CloseFile(Vhod);
  CloseFile(Vihod);
end;
```

Comment: непонятна суть вопроса

Comment: @Igor, ну хотелось бы поиск осуществлять через словарь дабы ускорить работу функции Pos.

Comment: Что должен делать этот код?

Comment: @Igor, ну я ввожу одно слово в memo или список слов и по этим ключевым словам ищутся все строки что в текстовом файле и записываются в другой текстовый файл.

Comment: может будет быстрее, а может нет. Почему бы Вам не засечь время для двух вариантов?

Comment: @Igor, ну я просто не могу правильно оформить код с Dictionary. А без него, я делал передачу из массива memo в pos и у меня получился результат: Файл в 60 мегабайт - 30 секунд. А хотелось бы понять как сделать через Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле много повторяющихся строк?

```
dictYes := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create;
dictNo := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create;

while not Eof(Vhod) do
begin
  ReadLn(Vhod, S);

  if dictYes.ContainsKey(S) then
  begin
    WriteLn(Vihod, S);
  end
  else if not dictNo.ContainsKey(S) then
  begin
    if Pos('Что ищем', S) > 0 then
    begin
      dictYes.Add(S, 1);
      WriteLn(Vihod, S);
    end
    else
    begin
      dictNo.Add(S, 1);
    end;    
  end;

end;

dictNo.Free;
dictYes.Free;
```

Comment: Да, практически 45%. То есть тут есть какая то особенность ?

Comment: @Денис Если одинаковых строк нет или мало, то словарь только помешает.

Comment: Сделал, как Вы сказали и при открытии файла: Сразу пишет вот такое сообщение -  Item not Found

Comment: Спасибо заработало, но скорость и в самом деле не увеличилась. По сути даже уменьшилась. По сути дела это максимум что можно выжать с словаря TDictionary ?

Comment: @Денис Видимо - да.